# How to store fgets string results into an char array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, fgets

I am currently getting the following error

```
Process terminated with status -1073741819
```

and I suspect its my `fgets()` but I have no idea why this is happening, any help would be much appreciated.

```
 //Gets Dictionary from file
    char* GetDictionary() {
        int ArraySize;
        int i = 0;
        FILE * DictionaryFile;

        //Gets first line (in this case it is the amount of Lines)
        DictionaryFile = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
        fscanf(DictionaryFile,"%d", &ArraySize);
        ArraySize = ArraySize + 1;
        printf("%d", ArraySize);
        fclose(DictionaryFile);

        //Gets the array
        char* Dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char)*ArraySize);
        char Temp[ArraySize];
        char TempArray[ArraySize];

        DictionaryFile = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
        while(fgets(Temp, sizeof Temp, DictionaryFile)!=NULL) {
          Dictionary[i] = Temp;
          //Check The array
          printf("%s", Dictionary[i]);
          i++;
        }

        fclose(DictionaryFile);
        return Dictionary;
    }
```

Comment: Equally Bad: `Dictionary[i] = Temp;` - if that doesn't spew a warning from your compiler, you seriously need to crank up the warning level. That tries to save a `char*` to a `char`. And `printf("%s", Dictionary[i]);` isn't any better, sending a `char` promoted to `int` to a format specifier expecting `char*`.

Comment: Closing the file and reopening it resets the file pointer to the beginning, so you'll read the array size again. I'm guessing you don't want that. Also, you should check that `Dictionary != NULL` after calling `fopen`. Failure to do so will result in a crash, if `fopen` wasn't able to open the file.

Comment: Does  `ArraySize` represent the number of remaining characters or the number of remaining lines of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1073741819 --> C0000005 and likely has some significance.  Maybe use below to discern its meaning.

```
puts(strerror(-1073741819));
```

Code has many issues: Here are some corrected to get you going.

1) Allocate an array of pointers, not an array of `char`

```
// char* Dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char)*ArraySize);
char** Dictionary = malloc(ArraySize * sizeof *Dictionary);
```

2) Form a big buffer to read each line

```
 char Temp[100];
```

3) After reading each line, get rid of the likely trailing `'\n'`

```
 size_t len = strlen(Temp);
 if (len && Temp[len-1] == '\n') Temp[--len] = 0;
```

4) Allocate memory for that word and save

```
 Dictionary[i] = malloc(len + 1);
 assert(Dictionary[i]);
 memcpy(Dictionary[i], Temp, len + 1);
```

5) Robust code frees it allocations before completion

6) Code reads "amount of Lines" twice as file is opened twice. Just leave file open (and not re-open it). [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406357/how-to-store-fgets-string-results-into-an-char-array/32407684#comment52681183_32406357)

Answer (score 0):

You likely want `Dictionary` to be an array of char strings.  That is, `Dictionary` is an array, and each element in the array is a `char *`.  That makes `Dictionary` a `char **`.

For this example, it may be most straightforward to allocate memory for the `Dictionary` array itself, then allocate memory for its contents.  You'll need to free all this when you're done, of course.

```
char **Dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char *) * ArraySize);
for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) {
    Dictionary[i] = malloc(ArraySize);
}
```

There are better ways to do this.  For one, you might only allocate memory when you need it, for each `fgets()` return.  You could also use `strdup()` to allocate only the memory you need.  You could also pass in `Dictionary` from the caller, already allocated, so you don't worry about allocating it here.

Later in your program, as @WhozCraig pointed out, you need to copy the string in Temp, like `strcpy(Dictionary[i], Temp)`, in place of `Dictionary[i] = Temp`.  I too am surprised that's not generating a compiler warning!